# Showing the nth-match of grep

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep, match, echo

I am searching for a way to display only the n-th match of grep.

First I want to use `iwlist scan` to search for all networks, and then use `echo` and `grep` to output them.

```
for i in $(seq 1 15)
do
    iwlist scan > test.txt
    echo "Network $i : `grep i-th match test.txt`"
done
```

This is my first post, and I am new to bash-scripting, so please explain me how I am suposed to write my script.

Comment: You can use `sed`: `grep $pattern $file | sed -n "${i}p"`

Comment: What text do you want to match? and why is there a  `15` in the first line of the script? .

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and add concise, testable sample input and expected output to your question so we can help you.